# How to connect Iphone to reflector 2 tool

Tags: windows-7-x64, iphone-6

I have seen so many posts regarding this but none of them worked for me.I want to connect Iphone 6 to Reflector 2 tool present in a laptop having windows 7 in it.They both are in same wifi network.Everything is of latest version.But Airplay option is not coming in Iphone and Relector 2 tool is also not recognizing the iphone.I know there is no issue with the network.I also saw some posts which say that Reflector 2 tool make its own firewall rule,just allow it.But in my firewall there are no rules related to reflector 2.What may be the problem .Can any body help ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble with Reflector as well. Switching to [AirServer](http://airserver.com) was the fix for me. It's basically the same thing except more stable.